# How to transfer a filr from Unix Server to my windows machine

Tags: unix

I am performing some automate validation in Unix machine using jenkins. I have to trasnfer a file from Unix machine to my local windows machine to upload it in HP ALM.

Is there any automation script which ca perform this task?

Comment: You should expect to have products and or scripts recommendations as such topics are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Launch your jenkins slave via Java web start (Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes > Launch method), you need to specify remote root directory where you need 
once your slave is configured go to windows machine and inside your browser hit jenkins server 
and now start your slave which will open a pop up window and everything goes well it will show as connected 
Now inside your job> build settings restrict your build to be run on windows slave you have configured.
You are set and your files will get copied from unix machine to windows wuth use of jenkins